# Picture Tag Using data-srcset Instead of srcset

Tags: html, image, validation

I'm currently validating my HTML and am getting errors because my picture tags uses data-srcset instead of srcset. My question is, if I'm using data-srcset do I HAVE to use the srcset attribute for valid HTML? It would seem so.

Example:

```
<picture>
  <source data-srcset="assets/media/images/attorneys/img-attorney.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source data-srcset="assets/media/images/attorneys/img-attorney.png" type="image/jpg">
  <img src="assets/media/images/attorneys/img-attorney.png" class="lazy" alt="Attorney"> 
</picture>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; [`srcset` is mandatory](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-source-srcset) and the markup is not going to validate without it, even if you have substituted a `data-srcset` attribute with the same name. Custom data attributes can't substitute for standard ones of the same name for the purposes of validation; they're treated as custom and ignored.

However, if you intend to use `data-srcset` as a substitute for your own reasons, you may be able to write the standard `srcset` attribute in the HTML and use JavaScript to swap it out after the fact. Validators won't see this happening and will only see the `srcset` in the source markup. If you have client-side scripts that rely on this custom data attribute they may need to wait or listen for when this substitution has been performed.

Comment: Insightful answer. Some of these images are lazy loaded using a library, but the library does not append a srcset attribute to the tag.